# Ionic 4 Reactive Form Validation mobile app different to web

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have Reactive Form Validation working in an angular application.
I have replicated this code as similarly as possible in my ionic app and it works fine when running in the browser (ionic serve).

However when I run the same code on as a mobile app (Android or iOS) it does not update the validation messages.
How can I get the messages showing once the user leaves the input (touched) or after submitting the form and failing validation.

It knows the form is not valid once I submit it just just not show the messages.  It is also not a styling issue as they display if I remove all the conditional logic.

Code (works in browser):

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formCtrl="ngForm">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="row-padding-one"></ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size-sm="6" offset-sm="3" class="input-col">
            <ion-item class="custom-item" lines="none">
              <ion-input 
                class="login-input"
                formControlName="email"
                placeholder="E-Mail"
                required>
              </ion-input>
              <div *ngFor="let validation of loginValidationMessages.email">
                <div class="error-message"
                 *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && ((loginForm.get('email').dirty || loginForm.get('email').touched) || formCtrl.submitted)">
                  {{validation.message}}</div>
              </div>
            </ion-item>
...
           <ion-button
              class="btn-login"
              type="submit"
              color="primary"
              expand="block">Login
            </ion-button>
...
 </form>
```

.ts file:

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  fb = new FormBuilder();
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loginValidationMessages;
...
onSubmit() {
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    const email = this.loginForm.value.email;
    const password = this.loginForm.value.password;
    this.tempEmail = email;
    this.loginForm.reset();

    this.authenticate(email, password);
  }

initForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email:  new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      password:  new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ]))
    });

    this.loginValidationMessages = {
      email: [
        { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required' },
        { type: 'pattern', message: 'Enter a valid email' }
      ],
      password: [
        { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required' }
      ]
    };
  }
```

I have also tried the below and a few other combinations:

```
*ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && (loginForm.get('email').dirty || loginForm.get('email').touched)"
```

UPDATE:

The loginForm FormGroup is being updated.  I can see that when I console log during a submit.
However if I check/write the values in the template they do not change and just show the original values.  So the values in the template do not match the values in the .ts file:

```
<ion-row>
Required: {{loginForm.get('email').hasError('required')}}<br>
Pattern: {{loginForm.get('email').hasError('pattern')}}
</ion-row>
```

UPDATE 2:
Turns out no variables are updating on the template.
After a submit I set a global variable to "true" but it does not change when displayed on the page/template.  Looks like a change detection issue.
I am getting the following error after using my auth guard to redirect:

```
Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
```

And I have replicated this problem on the web.

Comment: can you update your formGroup in ts also? And we need to know how you validate when submit also

Comment: Apologies.  Added the code in the .ts

Comment: as a side note you should not do this `fb = new FormBuilder();`, you should inject FormBuilder in your constructor

Comment: If you are on a Mac you may be able to fake the useragent in Safari to act like Android. Then see if via debugging you get different results. I thought Chrome had that - but the articles I looked at seem out of date compared to v 76 I'm on.

Comment: @JGFMK I am using the fake mobile settings in windows chrome which I thought changed the user agent.  Although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I was not sure about that either. The other thought I had was use the ionic serve with the lab setting  `ionic serve --lab` to see how the behaviour changes. I was glad to see you solved it anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my route guard was causing the issue.
I was getting the warning in the console:

```
Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
```

So I added  `this.ngZone.run(() =>` to my route guard and it fixed the problem.
It was deceptive as I was not firing the route guard in the web as I was going straight to the login page but I was on the device as it was attempting to go to the home page first.

```
canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => this.ngZone.run(() => {
      if (user) {
        if (!this.authService.member) {
          this.authService.getMember(user.uid).then(member => {
            // Reload adminUser data
            this.authService.member = member;
            resolve(true);
          });
        } else {
          resolve(true);
        }
      } else {
        // Remove adminUser data
        this.authService.member = null;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        resolve(false);
      }
    }));
  });
```